# A Sequelize column that cannot be updated

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, rest, sequelize.js

Is it possible to create a column on a MySQL table using Sequelize that can be initialized when creating a new row, but never updated?

For example, a REST service allows a user to update his profile. He can change any field except his `id`. I can strip the `id` from the request on the API route, but that's a little redundant because there are a number of different models that behave similarly. Ideally, I'd like to be able to define a constraint in Sequelize that prevents the `id` column from being set to anything other than `DEFAULT`.

Currently, I'm using a `setterMethod` for the `id` to manually throw a `ValidationError`, but this seems hackish, so I was wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing this. Even worse is that this implementation still allows the `id` to be set when creating a new record, but I don't know a way around this as when Sequelize generates the query it calls `setterMethods.id` to set the value to `DEFAULT`.

```
return sequelize.define('Foo',
    {
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        setterMethods: {
            id: function (value) {
                if (!this.isNewRecord) {
                    throw new sequelize.ValidationError(null, [
                        new sequelize.ValidationErrorItem('readonly', 'id may not be set', 'id', value)
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Just wondering the same. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4603

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at this Sequelize plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-noupdate-attributes

It adds support for no update and read-only attributes in Sequelize models.

In your specific case, you could configure the attribute with the following flags:

```
{
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique   : true,
    noUpdate : true
  }
}
```

That will allow the initial set of the `title` attribute if is null, and then prevent any further modifications once is already set.

*Disclaimer: I'm the plugin author.*