# Is it possible to create immutable field in sequelizejs?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Is there a way to make a field not modifiable in sequelize.js ?

```
var Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {
  name:  {
    type     : Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    immutable:true// <-- something like that
  },
 ...
});
```

I cant't find any documentation on the subject.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this would work for your situation, but you can look into the onUpdate property that you can add to the column properties.  http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499051/a-sequelize-column-that-cannot-be-updated) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Sequelize column that cannot be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499051/a-sequelize-column-that-cannot-be-updated)